# Anomaly for Majorana fermion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-anomalies, majorana-fermions

In 4-spacetime dimension, is there U(1) gauge field chiral anomaly associated with Majorana fermion (or I am not sure if it is equivalent, majorana representation)? Besides, I have read from several papers that there are gravitational chiral anomaly associated with both Dirac fermion and Majorana fermion. The only difference is the 1/2 factor in front of the anomaly term. Where does this difference appear in Fujikawa's chiral rotation method?

Comment: The $1/2$ difference in the perturbative gravitational anomaly is true in $1+1$ dimensions. The mathematical reason is probably that Grassmann integral for Majorana fermions gives a Pfaffian while for Dirac fermions you get a Determinant, and $\text{Det}=\text{Pf}^2$. Basically Majorana fermions have "half" degrees of freedom compared to Dirac fermions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Could you please also give me a clue or reference about what should the functional integral measure look like in the Majorana case? @Meng Cheng

Comment: @MengCheng I'm not sure this question has something to do with condensed-matter, does it ? In matter, there is no Majorana fermions, only Majorana mode (in short, the Majorana-staff exists only at zero energy, so it's not a particle as usual). I would naively guess there is no anomaly in condensed matter associated to the Majorana's physics, am I correct ?

Comment: @FraSchelle Majorana fermion (not zero modes) can show up in two ways: 1. Non-chiral version can arise as a critical theory, for example the critical point of the transverse Ising model in 1+1. 2. Chiral version shows up on the edge of 2d p+ip superconductor, which has gravitational anomaly.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks a lot, and sorry to disturb you one more time, but could you give me references for these exemples ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @FraSchelle Thanks for your comment! I am also interested in examples. I also have a followup question: does gravitational anomaly appears in 3D topological superconductor? If it exists, is it related to Majorana fermions on 2D surface?

Comment: @FraSchelle For chiral Majorana modes on the edge of p+ip, you can take a look at Read and Green http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9906453. The non-chiral one at the critical point of transverse Ising model should be covered in many textbooks, such as Subir Sachdev's "Quantum phase transitions".

Comment: @qc2014 There is no gravitational anomaly for the surface states of 3D topological superconductor, since the Majorana fermion there is only protected when there is time-reversal symmetry. In fact, you can realize exactly the same field theory in purely 2D systems but breaking time-reversal symmetry.